# .NET Core: PUT one boolean value without creating model

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, put

Can I put boolean value without creation additional model?
Currently my `Controller` `PUT` method is like this:

```
 public class InRequest 
 {
     public bool Val { get; set; }
 }

 [HttpPut("{id}/SetValue")]
 public IActionResult SetValue(Guid id, [FromBody] InRequest request)
 {

 }
```

From UI I am sending the following body:

```
{ val : value }
```

However, I thougt can I somehow get rid of model? Why we need to create model just for one value? However, if I am trying to send just `value` in `Body` and in `PUT` backend method receive just bool value, it never works.

Comment: Yes you can. The binding is by name so check your variable names.

Comment: You mean I can send the same body but in .NET method remove model and use just bool val?

Comment: Send it in route or in query , [FromQuery], [FromRoute]

Comment: HI @renathy,any update about this case?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the same body, you only need to send the value.

You can see my test here:

```
[HttpPut]
    public IActionResult SetValue([FromBody]bool Val)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

[image]